# SwiftUI, Combine, and Core Data -- Items not being mapped/displayed properly

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui, combine

I'm new to SwiftUI and Combine, and have a simple project that I'm using to test.  I'm using the `CDPublisher` class outlined in [this article](https://medium.com/better-programming/combine-publishers-and-core-data-424b68fe9473) to create the bridge between Core Data and Combine.  I have declared a Core Data entity class called `ItemEntity`.  It has a single property, a `String`, containing a serialized JSON object.  This object deserializes to a struct called `Item`.  My SwiftUI view simply displays a list of items returned from my ViewModel:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject
    var viewModel: MyListViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(viewModel.items, id: \.self.id) { item in
                    Text("\(item.name) - \(item.createdDate)")
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                self.viewModel.fetchItems()
            }
            .toolbar {
                Button(action: addItem) {
                    Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func addItem() {
        let entity = ItemEntity(context: viewContext)
        let rand = arc4random()
        var model = Item(name: "Item \(rand)", createdDate: Date())
        model.id = UUID().uuidString
        let jsonData = try! JSONEncoder().encode(model)
        
        entity.modelJSON = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            let nsError = error as NSError
            fatalError("\(nsError) - \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

My `ViewModel` makes use of the `CDPublisher` class to fetch the entities from Core Data.  It also has a map function that deserializes the JSON string in each entry to an `Item` instance.  Eventually, an `Array` of `Item` objects is what is made available via my `ViewModel`.  It looks like this:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData
import Combine
import SwiftUI

class MyListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    private var viewContext: NSManagedObjectContext =  PersistenceController.shared.container.viewContext
    
    @Published
    var items: [Item] = []
    
    private var cancellables = [AnyCancellable]()
    
    func fetchItems() {
        print("FETCHING...")
        
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let fetchReq: NSFetchRequest<ItemEntity> = ItemEntity.fetchRequest()
        CoreDataPublisher(request: fetchReq, context: self.viewContext)
            .map({ (entities: [ItemEntity]) -> [Item] in
                var items: [Item] = []
                entities.forEach { (entity: ItemEntity) in
                    if let json = entity.modelJSON?.data(using: .utf8) {
                        if let item = try? decoder.decode(Item.self, from: json) {
                            items.append(item)
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                return items
            })
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .replaceError(with: [])
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
            .sink { completion in
                print("COMPLETION : \(completion)")
            } receiveValue: { items in
                print("SUCCESS")
                items.forEach { (item) in
                    print("\t\(item)")
                }
                self.items = items
            }.store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```

My code compiles and runs successfully.  I see print statements originating via my `fetchItems()` method, indicating that my items array contains all of the objects expected:

```
FETCHING...
SUCCESS
    Item(name: "Item 854277542", createdDate: 2021-01-25 19:19:16 +0000)
    Item(name: "Item 92334228", createdDate: 2021-01-25 19:19:17 +0000)
    Item(name: "Item 405319813", createdDate: 2021-01-25 19:19:18 +0000)
    Item(name: "Item 121330574", createdDate: 2021-01-25 19:19:18 +0000)
    Item(name: "Item 3025980536", createdDate: 2021-01-25 19:19:19 +0000)
    Item(name: "Item 1278077958", createdDate: 2021-01-25 19:19:19 +0000)
    Item(name: "Item 4274618146", createdDate: 2021-01-25 19:19:19 +0000)
    Item(name: "Item 2320455869", createdDate: 2021-01-25 19:19:19 +0000)
    Item(name: "Item 3542559526", createdDate: 2021-01-25 19:19:22 +0000)
    Item(name: "Item 4217121551", createdDate: 2021-01-25 19:19:23 +0000)
    Item(name: "Item 4139555338", createdDate: 2021-01-25 19:19:24 +0000)
    Item(name: "Item 1345067436", createdDate: 2021-01-25 19:20:49 +0000)
```

However, my UI is not displaying the items as expected.  I would expect a row for each `Item` object.  Instead, I see multiple rows but they all have the exact same text matching the *first* `Item` in my array.  It's essentially the same row repeated over and over again.

I'm obviously doing something wrong here, but I'm not experienced enough to know exactly what.  Why is it that my items property has the correct values, but I'm not seeing that reflected in my UI?  Is it due to my map function and the JSON decoding?  (Also, is there a better way to accomplish mapping an array of `ItemEntity` entities to an array of `Item` objects?)  Any hints?

**UPDATE:**  Below is the definition for my `Item` struct

```
import Foundation

struct Item {
    
    var name: String = ""
    var createdDate: Date = Date()
    
}

extension Item: Codable {
    
}

extension Item: Identifiable {
    private struct IdentifiableHolder {
        static var _id: String = ""
    }
    
    var id: String {
        get {
            return IdentifiableHolder._id
        }
        set(newId) {
            IdentifiableHolder._id = newId
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the declaration of Item. My guess is that something is wrong with your definition of Item — just a guess, because it is not shown in your question. Nothing about the code you _have_ shown ensures that your decoded Item objects have unique `id` values — but the List depends upon these.

Comment: @matt Added the Item object.

Comment: Yup, well, I still don't see how your decoded Item objects (in the Combine pipeline) end up with anything other than `""` as their `id`. And that would explain the issue, wouldn't it? Personally I would be inclined to give Item an initializer such that making an Item by supplying a name and date will also _automatically_ apply a unique `id`.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing about the code you have shown for `fetchItems` ensures that your decoded Item objects have unique `id` values — but the List explicitly depends upon these (`id: \.self.id`). Instead, all your Item objects have the default `id`, which is `""`. Thus the `id` of *every* Item object is the `id` of the *first* Item object, explaining the phenomenon.

You might have been after something like this:

```
struct Item : Codable {
    var name: String = ""
    var createdDate: Date = Date()
    private var idHolder = IdentifiableHolder(id: UUID().uuidString)
}

extension Item: Identifiable {
    private struct IdentifiableHolder : Codable {
        var id: String = ""
    }
    var id: String {
        get {
            return idHolder.id
        }
        set(newId) {
            idHolder.id = newId
        }
    }
}
```

Now every Item has a unique ID and it is stored and retrieved as part of its Codable implementation.

Comment: Looks like you're correct.  I moved the id property into the struct itself instead of an extension and it worked as expected.  Interesting.  Can I not add JSON-encodable properties via extension?  I would think that adding them that way would cause them to be picked up as expected, but it looks like they are not.  Is there a way to get that behavior?

Comment: I don't know what you have now or what you mean by "moved the id property into the struct itself". I don't believe that the extension per se has anything to do with the matter. I believe I have answered that question as asked.

Comment: If you look at the code for Item that I posted, the Item struct originally only had the name and createdDate properties.  The id property was added as an extension.  Getting rid of that extension and creating an id property in the Item struct itself corrected the issue.  I was under the assumption that properties in the extension would be serialized to JSON just as properties in the struct itself.  It would appear that this is not the case.

Comment: _Stored_ properties. As currently defined, you have no `id` "property" per se; it is a _computed_ property, and so is just some functions. Moreover, there are no IdentifiableHolder instances in the story; it is just a wrapper for a static method, and is not Codable. So again, it has nothing to do with the "extension". It has to do with the fact that you have no true `id` property at all.

Comment: The only thing it _does_ have to do with the extension is that you can't declare a stored property in an extension. I've added to my answer the sort of thing you _might_ have been after.